# Query not using index in exists statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, query-optimization

I have the index `IDX_tbl_SpeedRun_StatusTypeID_GameID_CategoryID_LevelID_PlusInclude` on table `dbo.tbl_SpeedRun` below. The exists statement in the query below is taking a while (1m 10s) saying there is a missing index ON `[dbo].[tbl_SpeedRun] ([StatusTypeID],[LevelID])`.

Why is the `exists` statement not using the index I created? It already includes the columns `[StatusTypeID],[LevelID]`.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_SpeedRun] 
( 
    [OrderValue] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [ID] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL, 
    [StatusTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GameID] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryID] [varchar] (50) NOT NULL,
    [LevelID] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [SubCategoryVariableValues] [varchar] (1000) NULL,
    [PlayerIDs] [varchar] (1000) NULL,
    [PlatformID] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [RegionID] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [IsEmulated] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Rank] [int] NULL,
    [PrimaryTime] [bigint] NULL,
    [RealTime] [bigint] NULL,
    [RealTimeWithoutLoads] [bigint] NULL,
    [GameTime] [bigint] NULL,
    [Comment] [varchar] (MAX) NULL,
    [ExaminerUserID] [varchar] (50) NULL, 
    [RejectReason] [varchar] (MAX) NULL, 
    [SpeedRunComUrl] [varchar] (2000) NOT NULL,
    [SplitsUrl] [varchar] (2000) NULL,
    [RunDate] [datetime] NULL,  
    [DateSubmitted] [datetime] NULL,   
    [VerifyDate] [datetime] NULL,   
    [ImportedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_SpeedRun_ImportedDate] DEFAULT(GETDATE()),
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO 

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tbl_SpeedRun] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_SpeedRun] 
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ID]) WITH (FILLFACTOR=90) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_tbl_SpeedRun_OrderValue] 
    ON [dbo].[tbl_SpeedRun] ([OrderValue]) WITH (FILLFACTOR=90) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_tbl_SpeedRun_StatusTypeID_GameID_CategoryID_LevelID_PlusInclude] 
    ON [dbo].[tbl_SpeedRun] ([StatusTypeID], [GameID], [CategoryID],[LevelID]) 
       INCLUDE ([SubCategoryVariableValues], [PlayerIDs], [Rank],[PrimaryTime])
GO
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tbl_SpeedRun rn WITH (NOLOCK) 
                    WHERE rn.LevelID = l.ID AND rn.StatusTypeID = 1) 
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
    END
FROM
    dbo.tbl_Level l WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    l.GameID = 'pd0wq901'
ORDER BY 
    l.OrderValue
```

Comment: Why are you using the `NOLOCK` hint against against object? You do understand the implications of it correct? Are you saying you're happy with incorrect and/or inconsistent results?

Comment: Yes, there's is an import task that runs every 5 mins against the table, I need nolock to prevent lockups when accessing the table. Unless I'm misunderstanding, anytime I have a constant import hitting a table I use nolock on the queries hitting the table.

Comment: I wouldn't do it just *anytime* you have an import. `NOLOCK` has serious implications for data correctness, and you must find other methods to maintain concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `from` clause of your subquery:

```
WHERE rn.LevelID = l.ID AND rn.StatusTypeID = 1
```

A helpful index for this predicate would involve the two columns, in any order.

Your existing index does not satisfy that requirement. It has columns:

```
[StatusTypeID], [GameID], [CategoryID], [LevelID]) 
INCLUDE ([SubCategoryVariableValues], [PlayerIDs], [Rank], [PrimaryTime])
```

Both columns are here, but buried within others  - so the database cannot take advantage of it to speed up the subquery.

Bottom line: creating a large index that involves a lot of columns does not speed up queries by default. Instead, you can analyze each query individually and define the proper optimization.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought the index could include additional columns in the key, and it would just use the columns that it was trying to access. You're saying it should only be the 2 columns being accessed in order to pick up the index?

Comment: @mgmedick: yes. Or, at least, these two columns should appear *first* in an index that may involve other columns as well.

Comment: Ok I thought the ordering of the columns in the Key didn't matter, so I combined several indexes that where referencing the same columns in the Key. I also read somewhere that having the same columns in the Key on multiple non-clustered indexes could cause perforamnce problems, so I tried to combine into one.

Comment: @mgmedick Think of an index on two columns as being like a telephone directory (?!) that is sorted by `Last Name, First Name`. If you want to find Bob Smith you just look (_seek_) for `'Smith'` first, then `'Bob'`. If you get to `'Smith', 'Bubba'` then you know there wasn't a `'Bob'` and you quit. If you want to find Alice, but don't know the last name, then you can only _scan_ the entire index (or table). There might be a benefit in scanning the index rather than the table, e.g. if the table has large rows then you might have fewer physical reads scanning the index.